# XPath - Get nodes with distinct text values from a non repetitive list

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have an XML as below :

```
<object>
    <codes>
        <cd1>A</cd1>
        <cd2>B</cd2>
        <cd3>C</cd3>
    </codes>
    <codes>
        <cd1>A</cd1>
        <cd2>D</cd2>
        <cd3></cd3>
    </codes>
    <codes>
        <cd1>E</cd1>
        <cd2>D</cd2>
        <cd3></cd3>
    </codes>
</object>
```

So far my XPath evolution has been as below :

1. `//cd1|//cd2|//cd3` : Gets all cd1, cd2 and cd3 elements
2. `(//cd1|//cd2|//cd3)[text()[1]]` : Filters all elements with non-empty text value from above list and returns the below elements.

   `<cd1>A</cd1>
   <cd2>B</cd2>
   <cd3>C</cd3>
   <cd1>A</cd1>
   <cd2>D</cd2>
   <cd1>E</cd1>
   <cd2>D</cd2>`
3. Now I need to remove the elements that have repeating text values. I have tried xpath as `(//cd1|//cd2|//cd3)[text()[1]][(preceding::cd1)|(preceding::cd2)|(preceding::cd3)]` . What I am 
   hoping to achieve is to check whether the value is preceding in any of cd1 or cd2 or cd3 above. But this returns below where `<cd2>D</cd2>` is repeating.

   `<cd2>B</cd2>
   <cd3>C</cd3>
   <cd1>A</cd1>
   <cd2>D</cd2>
   <cd1>E</cd1>
   <cd2>D</cd2>`

How can I write an xpath to solve above (3) ?

Please note I have to use Xpath 1.0 , therefore distinct-values function is not an option. Also, I need to get the matching node list, not the text values from the xpath, since I have to do some more processing on these nodes using AXIOM.

Update : I am using this xpath to get matching elements which will be then processed with AXIOM. Therefore, I need to write a single xpath expression to get the matching elements in one go (I cannot write custom flows in AXIOM or using XSLT). Also cd* cannot be used because the real names are not matching. I have used a sample here.

Comment: could  you change the naming of the elements.  i suggest to change every cdX element to a cd element.

Comment: I do not have control over it. If so it would have been much straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//cd1[not(text() = preceding::cd1/text())][normalize-space()]|
//cd2[not(text() = preceding::cd2/text())][normalize-space()]|
//cd3[not(text() = preceding::cd3/text())][normalize-space()]
```

Comment: I modified this xpath a little to validate uniqueness among all previous categories as below. `//cd1[not(text() = preceding::cd1/text())][not(text() = preceding::cd2/text())][not(text() = preceding::cd3/text())][normalize-space()]|//cd2[not(text() = preceding::cd1/text())][not(text() = preceding::cd2/text())][not(text() = preceding::cd3/text())][normalize-space()]|//cd3[not(text() = preceding::cd1/text())][not(text() = preceding::cd2/text())][not(text() = preceding::cd3/text())][normalize-space()]`

Answer (score 1):

One way I found is with following template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[starts-with(node-name(.), 'cd')]">
        <xsl:variable name="content"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:if test="count(preceding::*[starts-with(node-name(.), 'cd') and text() = $content]) = 0 and text()">
               <xsl:copy-of select="."/> 
            </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This takes all cd* elements, and takes the content for each of them, which it uses to count how many preceding with the same content there are - if thats 0 -> then it uses it.

As far as I know this is the only way this can be done in xslt-1 (by using a variable). This is because you cannot back-reference within the xpath - unless you have the value in the variable (and you need to compare the "current" (outside) text with the "current" (node within the xpath) text).

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this does the job, it will be far less efficient than the Munechian method - FYI.

Comment: cd* is not possible since the real names are rather different. I have posted a sample here.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty straightforward Muenchian grouping, just with three keys:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:key name="cd1" match="//cd1" use="text()" />
<xsl:key name="cd2" match="//cd2" use="text()" />
<xsl:key name="cd3" match="//cd3" use="text()" />

<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:for-each select="/object/codes/cd1[./text() != '' and count(. | key('cd1', .)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="/object/codes/cd2[./text() != '' and count(. | key('cd2', .)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="/object/codes/cd3[./text() != '' and count(. | key('cd3', .)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cd1>A</cd1>
<cd1>E</cd1>
<cd2>B</cd2>
<cd2>D</cd2>
<cd3>C</cd3>
```

Alternatively, if you want to group them regardless of node name (i.e. if `cd1` and `cd2` both have `A` as the text value), it's a little less straightforward.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
<xsl:key name="cd" match="//cd1 | //cd2 | //cd3" use="text()" />

<xsl:template match="/">    
    <xsl:for-each select="/object/codes/cd1[./text() != '' and count(. | key('cd', .)[1]) = 1] | /object/codes/cd2[./text() != '' and count(. | key('cd', .)[1]) = 1] | /object/codes/cd3[./text() != '' and count(. | key('cd', .)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This would give the same output as above (but ordered the way your current template outputs), but would eliminate duplicates between a `cd1`, `cd2`, or `cd3` sharing the same text (and only take the first one that has it).

Also note that I'm ignoring empty nodes - that may not be desired (and can be easily fixed by removing `./text() != ''` from the selectors - however, a different method would have to be used to eliminate duplicate empty nodes if that was desired (probably just a series of templates or `xsl:if`s that test for an empty node and output a single one if any exist in that case).

Comment: I am actually using this xpath and using with axiom. Therefore, is there a single xpath which I can use to select the elements? I have no control over the axiom logic. I just need to get the correct elements with a single xpath expression and pass it on. I am not able to use any structured flows as in xslt. Updated the question

Comment: I don't believe it's possible using just XPath.  Maybe Axiom has some other facility for it?  I'm not familiar with Axiom.